# how to get firebase cloud functions to work with flutter

Tags: node.js, flutter, google-cloud-functions

So I am new to flutter and developing in general and I have been stuck on a problem for days now. I am trying to get my Flutter app to access a cloud function to get a response from an api. The trouble I am having is with node.js. I am complete noob to Flutter and node.js is confusing me. When I run the app and push the button to get the function all I get is null. The firebase console logs an appropriate response, so I know the code works its just I need to get the response to send to my flutter app. I need to get the node.js "body" constant to go to my app. please help! many thanks in return!
I have tried many different attempts, but here is the latest node.js code attempt:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const https = require("follow-redirects").https;

const qs = require("querystring");

exports.yodleeAuth = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "hostname": "development.api.com",
    "path": "/ysl/auth/token",
    "headers": {
      "Api-Version": "1.1",
      "loginName": "loginName",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    "maxRedirects": 20,
  };

  const req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    const chunks = [];

    res.on("data", function(chunk) {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    res.on("end", function(chunk) {
      const body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
      console.log(body.toString());
      return body;
    });

    res.on("error", function(error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
  });

  const postData = qs.stringify({
    "clientId": "123456789abcdefgh",
    "secret": "123456789abcdefgh",
  });

  req.write(postData);
  
  req.end();
});
```

Here is the Flutter code:

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        elevation: 1,
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: kGold,
        ),
        onPressed: () async{
          HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable(
              'yodleeAuth'
          );
          await callable().then((value) {
            print(value.data);
          });
        },
```

Comment: This is a problem with resolving async data. It's being logged correctly as the console.log is inside the `res.on("end"...` portion. You're trying to write to the request output before that event is fired.

Comment: What should I do?